# work around setting variables in django templates

Tags: django, templates

I have this code that I used from twig to display sections according to the same date.

I'm trying to use the same code in Django but I can't set variables in its template system. What is the sane way to do this? The correct way? How do people tackle such a problem?

```
{% set date = "prout" %}

{% for article in articles %}
  {% if article.date != date %}
     {% if date != "prout" %} 
          </ul>
        </section>
     {% endif %}

     {% set date = article.date %}

     <section class="row">
        <h2>{{ article.date }}</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>+ {{ article.titre }}</li>
  {% else %}
      <li>+ {{ article.titre }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 </ul>
 </section>
```

Comment: You should do your logic in views not in templates. Also in django you can do {% with 'prout' as date %}

Comment: I'm pretty new to Django, I don't really know how I should do that. In views or in models?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django views : passing a dictionarry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810660/django-views-passing-a-dictionarry)

Answer (score 0):

The closer concept to 'set' variables is `with` tag. Quoting [Built-in template tags and filters django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

> **with**
>
> Caches a complex variable under a simpler name. This is useful
>   when accessing an “expensive” method (e.g., one that hits the
>   database) multiple times.

For example:

```
{% with total=business.employees.count %}
    {{ total }} employee{{ total|pluralize }}
{% endwith %}
```