# Django views : passing a dictionary

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I'm starting with Django (coming from CodeIgniter) and everything is very confusing...

I want to get my blog posts ordered by pub_date, and I want to display them in the templates grouped by month+year.

I tried this but obviously it's not working... And my knowledge of Python + Django is so bad that I don't see why not.

```
def index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    blogs_per_date = {}
    for blog in blogs:
        blogs_per_date[blog.pub_date.month + '-' + blog.pub_date.year] = blog
    context = {'blogs': blogs_per_date}
    return render(request, 'layout.html', context);
```

Here's my try with an object :

```
def index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    blogs_per_date = new object
    for blog in blogs:
        blogs_per_date.blog.(pub_date.month + ' ' + blog.pub_date.year) = blog
    context = {'blogs': blogs_per_date}
    return render(request, 'layout.html', context);
```

Comment: But a dictionary won't preserve the insertion order

Comment: So I should pass an object? But I really don't know how to do that. Can I do blogs_per_Date = new object ?

Comment: It depends on what you really want to do... I'm guessing you want to iterate over the blog objects you're passing and then show them in the page, in the same order you queried them

Comment: Here's an example of what I want to do : http://p1x3l.com/test

Comment: Keep in mind that dictionaries are similar to PHP associative arrays: you use them to access info using a key (that can be anything), not an index. But they *don't* keep the order of insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bypass this by using the [`regroup` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in your template.

```
{% regroup blogs by pub_date as blogs_by_date %}

<ul>
{% for blog in blogs_by_date %}
    <li>{{ blog.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in blog.list %}
          <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Your view now is simply:

```
def index(request):
    objects = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    return render(request, 'layout.html', {'blogs': objects})
```

If you want to do this in your view, you need to create a dictionary, where each key is the date object and the value is a list of blog objects. Something like this will work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def index(request):
    by_date = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date'):
        by_date[obj.pub_date].append(obj)
    return render(request, 'layout.html', {'blogs': by_date})
```

Now, in your `layout.html`, you have:

```
<ul>
{% for key,items in blogs.iteritems %}
    <li>{{ key }}
        <ul>
            {% for item in items %}
            <li>{{ item }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: you're the savior! I still wonder how I could have done it in the view though, I can do that in PHP in 3 seconds but I can't seem to do it in python